# Socket Program in Python Looping

Tags: python, sockets

What I am trying to do is get a letter from the client, send it to server, have the server make some changes and send it back. And then I want the client to display it. But I am having trouble making this into a loop. I want it to continuously ask for a letter until win is equal to true. How can I do that? I tried adding a while loop in the server side but got an error about a bad file descriptor. Thank you!

Client:

```
import sys
from socket import *

if sys.argv.__len__() != 3:
  serverName = 'localhost'
  serverPort = 5555
else:
  serverName = sys.argv[1]
  serverPort = int(sys.argv[2])

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)


clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))



# Get letter from user
letter = input('Guess a letter: ')

# Sends letter
letterBytes = letter.encode('utf-8')
clientSocket.send(letterBytes)

#Recieves newWord
newWordInBytes = clientSocket.recv(1024)
newWord = newWordInBytes.decode('utf-8')
print(newWord)

clientSocket.close()
```

Server:

```
     import sys

from socket import *

if sys.argv.__len__() != 2:
    serverPort = 5555
else:
    serverPort = int(sys.argv[1])

# This is a welcome socket
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)


serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)


serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))

# Listener begins listening
serverSocket.listen(1)

print("The server is ready to receive")

#Set secret word
word = 'arkansas'
linesForString = ' '    
#Prints out number of letters
for x in word:
    linesForString += '_ '


while 1:
    # Wait for connection and create a new socket
    # It blocks here waiting for connection
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    win = ' '
    #Sends lines of words
    linesInBytes = linesForString.encode('utf-8')
    connectionSocket.send(linesInBytes)

    while 1:

        # Receives Letter
        letter = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        letterString = letter.decode('utf-8')

        win = False 
        while win == False:
            newWord = ' '

            for x in word:
                 if(letterString == x):
                     newWord += x       
                 else:
                     newWord += '_ '

            #Sends newWord
            newWordInBytes = newWord.encode('utf-8')
            connectionSocket.send(newWordInBytes)

            if(newWord == 'Arkansas'):
                win = True
                print('You have won the game')
            else: 
                win = False
        # Close connection to client but do not close welcome socket
        connectionSocket.close()
```

Comment: You are not showing a complete example that we can test.

Comment: @Adirio I just added all my code! Thank you!

Comment: You are trying to send him ` _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ` but the client is not listening. Then the client is sending a letter and the server is receiving and decoding it and forming the new word with missing letters which the client is receiving and printing and then closing the connection. The server meanwhile re-makes the new word as the inner `while` didnt break and tries to send it again, on a closed connection, giving you that error. You have no way of knowing which letters he has guessed, you have no loops on the client side, you do not listen to the initial empty word in the client side.

Comment: @Adirio I am completely new to python socket programming, so could you maybe point me in the right direction on how to fix it? I am having trouble understanding the syncronization between the client and sever. Where would I put the loop in the clients side?

Comment: I think you may get it clear if you do something like this with your use case: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9b/CheckEmail.svg/440px-CheckEmail.svg.png

Answer (score 1):

This sequence diagram may help you build your app. Try to modify your program according to the diagram and tell us what problems you find.

[image: Sequence Diagram]